# Pass an object as a parameter Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

Does anyone here know how to pass an object as a parameter in the **DOM**.

I have here in my **HTML**

```
<div class="list-items">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let i of item">
            <span  (click)="onAdd({{newUser.username}},{{i}})" 
                   class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
            </span>
                {{ i.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I get an error for both `{{newUser.username}}` and for `{{i}}`.
I am more concerned about passing `{{i}}`.

Answer (score 2):

You only need string interpolation (`{{variable}}`) on using variables in your template. For bindings and events you can directly use it like so:

```html
<span (click)="onAdd(newUser.username, i)" 
      [someInput]="foobar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
</span>
```